# Which is the package name on the build gradle?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm trying to set the push notifications using firebase. During the setup it asks for the package name which is supposed to be on build.gradle and should look like this

> com.yourapp.android

But I can't find anything like that...
You guys know where to find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look for `applicationId` in your build.gradle.  That value is your app's unique package name.

Alternately, it may be that ionic adds code to use the "package" attribute value from AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Thanks! In Build.gradle I found this         versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")
 I dont think is that...

Comment: Also I found this in android.json                         {
                            "xml": "<receiver android:exported=\"true\" android:name=\"com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver\" android:permission=\"com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND\"><intent-filter><action android:name=\"com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE\" /><category android:name=\"${applicationId}\" /></intent-filter></receiver>",
                            "count": 1
                        },

Comment: could be this in build.gradle? Can I change it? apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Answer (score 2):

You can find the application package name and version code from config.xml in ionic project. In config.xml what ever specified in the widget id will be the package name.

```
<widget id="com.yourapp.hybrid" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```